# Some doubts about WordPress theme\plugin development IDE, how to obtain the IDE code assistance?

Tags: ide, wordpress-theming, aptana, wordpress

I am pretty new in WordPress theme\plugin development (I came from Java and C#) and I have the following doubt about the IDE and how to correctly handle the WordPress development process.

My main doubt is this one: when I develop in Java I use Eclipse as IDE and using Eclipse I can navigate through classes and methods selecting it with mouse pointer and clicking CTRL on the keyboard (I select a method, I press CTRL and it open me this method implementation).

Also using Eclipse\Visual Studio if I put the mouse pointer on a method call in my code I can obtain some informations about it, as the returned type or the input parameters list.

Now I am using **Aptana Studio 3** to develop a WordPress theme. I imported the entire WP installation directory as a project and I am working on my custom theme but I have not all the previous feature.

What can I do to have these feature when I develop a WordPress theme or a plugin?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You might try Jetbrains' PHPStorm. Version 8 which is only available via their [early access program](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) has [Wordpress support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/wordpress-support-in-phpstorm-8-eap/). I have not used Aptana very much but PHPStorm has been very helpful. It's got a hefty price tag but there is a 30 day trial.

Helpful link
[PHPStorm Wordpress documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/WordPress+Development+using+PhpStorm)